# Populating textboxes in form but after submit data does not reach database

Tags: javascript

I have a form that uses this autocomplete for two address fields. Everything works except when the city, state and zipcode are extracted to the respected textboxes after submitting nothing shows in my database. I am thinking it has something to do with dispatchEvent method but I am not sure. If I manually type in the textboxes the database is populated. This only doesn't work because I am trying programmatically.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places"></script>

<script>
// Define the options for the autocomplete objects
var options = {
  types: ['address']
};

// Create the first autocomplete object for the first textbox
var input1 = document.querySelector('input[name="address"]');
autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1, options);
autocomplete1.setFields(['address_component']);
autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress1);

// Create the second autocomplete object for the second textbox
var input2 = document.querySelector('input[name="kmfjZ9qMYayFYs83jeCL"]');
autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2, options);
autocomplete2.setFields(['address_component']);
autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress2);

// Define the fillInAddress function for the first textbox
function fillInAddress1() {
var place = autocomplete1.getPlace();

 if (place.formatted_address) {
    var addressInput = document.getElementById('address');
    addressInput.value = place.formatted_address;
  }
  // Extract the city, state, and postal code from the selected place
  var cityInput = document.getElementById('city');
  var stateInput = document.getElementById('state');
  var postalCodeInput = document.getElementById('postal_code');
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var component = place.address_components[i];
    if (component.types.includes('locality')) {
      cityInput.value = component.long_name;
    }
    if (component.types.includes('administrative_area_level_1')) {
      stateInput.value = component.short_name;
    }
    if (component.types.includes('postal_code')) {
      postalCodeInput.value = component.long_name;
    }
 if (component.types.includes('street_number')) {
      var addressNumber = component.long_name;
    }
    if (component.types.includes('route')) {
      var streetName = component.long_name;
    }
if (addressNumber && streetName) {
    var addressInput = document.getElementById('address');
    addressInput.value = addressNumber + ' ' + streetName;
  }
}
  var address = document.querySelector('input[name="address"]')
  var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  e.initEvent('input', true, true);
  address.dispatchEvent(e);
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector(".pac-container").style.display = "none"
  },1000)

}



// Define the fillInAddress function for the second textbox
function fillInAddress2() {
  var address = document.querySelector('input[name="kmfjZ9qMYayFYs83jeCL"]')
  var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  e.initEvent('input', true, true);
  address.dispatchEvent(e);
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector(".pac-container").style.display = "none"
  },1000)
}
</script>
```